# Custom JavaScript garbage collector

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I don't want to create a wheel from scratch. But I am curious if there were JavaScript library named `gc.js` what would it looks like? How can I write custom garbage collector for JavaScript in JavaScript (if possible)?

Comment: Garbage collection is not implemented in JavaScript code, but is built-in to the language runtime (browser, node.js, V8, etc.).

Comment: @Brandon That's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collection is done by the execution environment of your code. It is not accessible from the JavaScript code itself - at least it is not specified to be, yet an engine can decide to expose a custom interface to the native functions ([example for node.js](https://github.com/billywhizz/node-gc)).

If you would write the whole garbage collector in JavaScript, that would imply that your JavaScript engine itself is [partly] written in JavaScript.